# Import 400 rows in 20k row sheet and manipulate before import

Tags: vba, excel, optimization, pivot-table

I have 2 sheets with only 2 columns:

- Old URL
- New URL

One sheet (master) contains 20k rows of those two columns and I have another sheet (toImport) with about 400 rows of those same two columns.

Since it's for a redirect file sent to apache and I do this because of a big structure change in our web environment, before importing those 400 rows in the 20k rows sheet I want to evaluate some scenarios:

- If the old and new pair from the toImport file is already in the master file: do nothing with it
- If the old URL from the toImport file is in the new URL column from the master file, do the following:
- Put the new URL value from toImport file in the new URL value of master (in order not to create a cascading redirection)
- Also import the old/new pair from toImport, as-is in the master file (in order for users to access the new page if they knew the last active URL).

In other words, if I have, in the master file

a -> b

and in the toImport file

b -> c

I want to be able to do the following in the master file

a -> c

b -> c

What would be the best approach for this?  VBA I suppose, or pivot table?  Can someone gives me some ideas about how to address that.  Knowing that 20k rows looped 400 times can be long, their must be a quick way to work this but I have no clue.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How often do you need to do this?  If you need to repeat this daily, than yeah, perhaps VBA. Otherwise, I wouldn't recommend it. I'd recommend just using some lookups, (ie MATCH) or such and verify things, then import them.

Comment: I always recommend pivot tables and/or formulas over VBA when possible

Comment: @Ditto: Thanks, I don't have to run this often (just on big projects that comes about three times a year.)  The rest of the time I only have to had 2-3 rows at a time and the "find" is much easier than this bulk task.  Why not recommanding VBA,

Comment: With my given example, would it be too much to ask for a real formula to test what I want.  I really don't know how to do this either in pivot tables or formula and I would be thankfull to understand either fashion.

Comment: VBA is more complex to write and maintain than just formulas (or as chancea said: pivot tables).  WIth simpler formulas, you could set those up and done.  You also have a chance to view the results prior to importing the data. VBA you'd likely have it just dump the items in as well .. and if it messed up, you'd have some rolling back to do ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info on why or not use VBA.  I'll test Isaac's solution.  Side question, why some use vlookup and other use index/match?  Would index/match be better for my purpose than vlookup?

Comment: I don't have any sources off hand but if I remember correctly h/vlookup is faster for binary searches while index/match is better for large amounts of data and it is more flexible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your Old URL and New URL are in columns A and B of the two sheets, you could do the following procedure:

1. Sort `master` and `toImport`, each by column A.
2. Add the following formula to column C of `master`:

   `= IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1, toImport!A:A, 1, FALSE)), IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B1, toImport!A:A, 1, FALSE)), B1, VLOOKUP(B1, toImport!A:B, 2, FALSE)), VLOOKUP(A1, toImport!A:B, 2, FALSE))`

   This will give you the New URL from `toImport` for rows whose Old URL or New URL in `master` matches the Old URL in `toImport` and the New URL from `master` for rows that don't.
3. Copy (or cut) Column C of `master` and Paste Values onto Column B.

   Now, you've handled the updates for everything on `toImport` that updates an existing URL on `master`.
4. Add the following to columns C and D of `toImport`:

   `= IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1, master!A:A, 1, FALSE)), A1, "")`
   `= IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1, master!A:A, 1, FALSE)), B1, "")`

   This will give you nonblank values only when `toImport` has a new value for Old URL.
5. Filter `toImport` for rows in which column C is not blank.
6. Copy the block of nonblank cells in columns C and D of `toImport`, and Paste Values to the bottom of columns A and B of `master`.

You could automate this process by recording a macro of a manual performance of the steps above. It shouldn't take too much to make this macro work in general.

Comment: Thanks Isaac, I'll certainly test that.  It seems to be the a really good and detailed answer.  Let me get back to you afterward.

Comment: Hello, I tested it and it doesn't seem to work as expected.
Let say in master I have "def -> efg" and in toImport "efg -> yxw".  I want the master line to be changed for "def -> yxw" and this doesn't seem to give me that opportunity.

Comment: Your description in #2 works great, by the way, for everything that changes the old URL from master to the new URL from toImport.

Comment: By the way, what would be the best stackoverflow way to add more details to my problem.  I only know the use of this comment box but can I use a "answer" to have more flexibility (screenshots...)?

Comment: @EricThibeault, to describe issues particular to a single answer, the best thing to do is comment on that answer. You can link to screenshots in a comment, if you want. To add details to the question, you can edit the question.

Comment: About my def, efg, yxw algebra... let's put it simple: I'll reuse the letters from my original post.  having a->b in master and b->c in toImport, I want master to be changed to a->c but the given formula let that row to a->b.

Comment: @EricThibeault, I updated Step 2 so that it will check both columns in `master`. Hopefully, this'll do the trick.

Comment: it has the same behavior than the earlier version of your code but it gives a #N/A if it finds the new url from master in the old url from toImport (b in my example).  Could it be the "A:B, **2**" part in the vlookup that gives this error (tries to retrieve value from a wrong cell)?

Comment: @EricThibeault, I split out consideration of master!New into a nested IF.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72180/discussion-between-eric-thibeault-and-isaac-moses).

Comment: Thanks, everything is now working really fine in a small section.  I'll now have to test it in my 20k and 400 rows sheets.

Answer (score 0):

I would get both sets of data in VBA variant arrays, then loop  to do the tests then put the arrays back. That would probably be fast enough. If its not fast enough then you could sort the data and use binary search.

The key trick is to get the entire range into an array using a single statement:

```
Dim vMaster as variant
vMaster=Worksheets("Master").Range("a1:B20400")
```

After updating the array you can write it back by reversing the assignment.